# Setting a VCProject property to default

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-macros

I'm trying some VS2005 IDE macros to modify a large amount of projects (~80) within a solution.  Some of the properties I wish to set do expose a programmatic interface to 'default', but many others do not. Is there a generic way to set such properties to their default? (eventually meaning erasing them from the .vcproj file)

Simplified example, setting some random properties:

```
   Sub SetSomeProps()
    Dim prj As VCProject
    Dim cfg As VCConfiguration
    Dim toolCompiler As VCCLCompilerTool
    Dim toolLinker As VCLinkerTool
    Dim EnvPrj As EnvDTE.Project

    For Each EnvPrj In DTE.Solution.Projects
        prj = EnvPrj.Object
        cfg = prj.Configurations.Item(1)


        toolLinker = cfg.Tools("VCLinkerTool")

        If toolLinker IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Some tool props that expose a *default* interface'
            toolLinker.EnableCOMDATFolding = optFoldingType.optFoldingDefault
            toolLinker.OptimizeReferences = optRefType.optReferencesDefault
            toolLinker.OptimizeForWindows98 = optWin98Type.optWin98Default
        End If

        toolCompiler = cfg.Tools("VCCLCompilerTool")

        If toolCompiler IsNot Nothing Then
            ' How to set it to default?  (*erase* the property from the .vcproj)'
            toolCompiler.CallingConvention = callingConventionOption.callConventionCDecl
            toolCompiler.WholeProgramOptimization = False
            toolCompiler.Detect64BitPortabilityProblems = False
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VS 2005, I believe you can use the [ClearToolProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcconfiguration_methods.aspx) method on VCConfiguration. The following code would accomplish this for CallingConvention (this is C#, but I'm sure something similar works for VB):

```
cfg.ClearToolProperty( toolCompiler, "CallingConvention" );
```

This would have the same effect as going into the GUI and choosing `"<inherit from parent or project defaults>"` for this option.

Unfortunately this seems to be deprecated in VS 2010, and I'm not sure what the new supported method is.

Comment: For VS2010, [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/vsx/thread/8dff2053-432f-4bdd-b668-3c88960e1409) suggests that you can cast the tool object to the new  [IVCRulePropertyStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.ivcrulepropertystorage.aspx) interface, then use its DeleteProperty method to get rid of the property.  I haven't been able to try this myself, though.